# Change color of custom shapes on HTML5 canvas using jQuery on mouseover?

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

I have this [code](https://jsfiddle.net/vehgm1wy/) for a map I am trying to make using HTML5 Canvas and jQuery. I have some of the shapes already made and the color filled in. What I don't know how to do is to make the color of the custom shapes change when the mouse is hovering over them. Any solutions?

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="700" height="485">
</canvas>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

     var tech = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
     tech.beginPath();
     tech.moveTo(250, 280);
     tech.lineTo(240, 280);
     tech.lineTo(240, 315);
     tech.lineTo(277, 315);
     tech.lineTo(277, 287);
     tech.lineTo(250, 287);
     tech.closePath();
     tech.stroke();
     tech.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3)";
     tech.fill();

     union = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
     union.beginPath();
     union.moveTo(400, 195);
     union.lineTo(386, 195);
     union.lineTo(386, 198);
     union.lineTo(364, 198);
     union.lineTo(364, 215);
     union.lineTo(386, 215);
     union.lineTo(386, 207);
     union.lineTo(400, 207);
     union.closePath();
     union.stroke();
     union.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3)";
     union.fill();

     cntr = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
     cntr.beginPath();
     cntr.moveTo(340, 196);
     cntr.lineTo(320, 196);
     cntr.lineTo(320, 222);
     cntr.lineTo(340, 222);
     cntr.closePath();
     cntr.stroke();
     cntr.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3)";
     cntr.fill();

     picho = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
     picho.beginPath();
     picho.moveTo(300, 240);
     picho.lineTo(285, 240);
     picho.lineTo(285, 250);
     picho.lineTo(300, 250);
     picho.closePath();
     picho.stroke();
     picho.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3)";
     picho.fill();
});
    </script>
```

Comment: you cannot change the color of canvas elements as they are not objects like in javascript. to change the color or modify the canvas element, you have to redraw them.

Comment: see this fiddle it exactly does what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/jackrugile/G7nDS/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use math to hit-test circular and rectangular shapes, but to test irregular shapes (such as yours) it's better to use `context.isPointInPath`.

`isPointInPath` works by testing if a specified [x,y] is inside the most recently defined path. That's means to test your irregular shape(s) you must first redefine each path and then test that redefined path with `isPointInPath`

"Redefine" means re-executing a particular path's code from `beginPath` to `closePath`. But there's no need to stroke or fill that defined path.

Here's example code and a demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
  var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  offsetX=BB.left;
  offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }

var isDown=false;
var startX,startY;

var paths=[];
paths.push([
  {x:400,y:95},
  {x:386,y:95},
  {x:386,y:98},
  {x:364,y:98},
  {x:364,y:115},
  {x:386,y:115},
  {x:386,y:107},
  {x:400,y:107}
]);

ctx.fillStyle='skyblue';

draw();

$("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});

function draw(highlight){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  for(var i=0;i<paths.length;i++){
    var path=paths[i];
    define(path);
    ctx.stroke();
    if(i==highlight){
      ctx.fill();
    }
  }
}

function define(p){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(p[0].x,p[0].y);
  for(var i=0; i<p.length;i++){
    ctx.lineTo(p[i].x,p[i].y);
  }
  ctx.closePath();
}

function handleMouseMove(e){

  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  var highlight=-1;
  for(var i=0;i<paths.length;i++){
    var path=paths[i];
    define(path);
    if(ctx.isPointInPath(mouseX,mouseY)){
      highlight=i;
    }
  }
  draw(highlight);

}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Move the mouse over the shape to highlight the shape</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=450 height=450></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you. This answered my answer perfectly. It does exactly what I need it to. Thank you! Making the points as x and y on an array makes things simpler as well I see.